# Hyphen in express route parameters

Tags: node.js, express, parameters

does anyone know if I can format my express route & parameters like:

```
app.get('/:a-:b-:c', (req, res) => {
 // a, b, c are parameters
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not understand the answers and in fact neither the questioner, the code in question should work 100%. Check it out here http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/ see also https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#:~:text=Since%20the%20hyphen,LAX%22%2C%20%22to%22%3A%20%22SFO%22%20%7D

Answer (score 3):

You just can go with regex routes, tried to search something with named capturing groups in js but is not possible so a trick from es6 will come very handy.

```
router.get(/^\/(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)?$/, function(req, res){
   const [a, b, c] = req.params;
   // a = req.params[0];
   // b = req.params[1];
   // c = req.params[2];

   // implement your logic
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way to handle multiple parameters, you will nest each parameter as an additional part of the route
Ive included a link to the routing page of express which also goes over this
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

```
 app.get('/:a/:b/:c', function(req, res) {
        var data = {
            "data": {
                "a": req.params.a,
                "b": req.params.b,
                "c": req.params.c

            }
        }; 

        send.json(data);
    });
```

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. You should check [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.